# JAXB mark field as required in generated wsdl

Tags: jaxb, annotations, wsdl

I have a JAXB-annotiated class with some required fields:

```
...
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
private String credentials = null;
...
```

Using SoapUI, the generated wsdl is like this:

```
...
<xs:element name="credentials" type="xs:string"/>
...
```

Is there any way to get the required-information into the wsdl? If I understood this right, than the wsdl should look like this (maybe that):

```
...
<xs:element wsdl:required="true" name="credentials" type="xs:string"/>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@XmlElement(required=true)` corresponds to an element in the XML Schema with the attribute `minOccurs="1"`.  Since this the default it is not required to be specified.

Comment: So all Elements without 'required=true' get a 'minOccurs="0"' in the wsdl, right?

Comment: Thx a lot, so I will stop searching ;-)